# How does one extract specific attributes of a label e.g. just the section number?

Tags: hyperref, cross-referencing

I'm using hyperref and calling `\autoref` to refer to tables, sections, chapters, etc.. However, sometimes I just want to refer to the *section number* of a table (*e.g.* **7.2** as opposed to **Table 7.2**).

How do we do this?

More generally, how do we extract the (5?) attributes of a label.
I know `\pageref` gets the page, but what about the others?

Also, some commands are issued in .aux like:

```
\@writefile{lot}{\contentsline
{figure}{\numberline
{5.2}{\ignorespaces Galois
Correspondence}}{20}{figure.5.2}}
```

How does extract, say, the 2.2nd attribute (`{\ignorespaces Galois Correspondence}`)?

Comment: In addition to @lockstep's answer, plain LaTeX also has the `\pageref` command.

Answer (score 9):

Use the `\ref` command (core LaTeX) and the `\nameref` command (provided by the [`nameref`](http://ctan.org/pkg/nameref) package, which is loaded by `hyperref`).

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}
\centering
(Table content)
\caption{foo}
\label{tab:foo}
\end{table}

This is a reference to \autoref{tab:foo}.

One could also refer to the number \ref{tab:foo} or to the name \nameref{tab:foo}.

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks **lockstep**, that answers an important part of my question. I have found the package "cleveref" (yes there's no double ‘r’), which sort of does some of the other things I was asking about (*e.g.* it is able to spit out the type of section which has been labelled — chapter, section, table, *etc.*). The question about the contents line thing still remains.